# Download all airflow logs

Tags: airflow

Is there a way to download all logs on the Airflow UI?

I'm working with legacy code and I have an error message I'd like to look up to find what job/dag it's appearing in, but I can't go searching one by one.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of deployment and logging mechanism do you use? Download from where? There are multiple answers to your question.

- If you deployed it on Kubernetes:

  - Using KubernetesExecutor

    - **Using Remote Logging**: you have all the logs at the remote logging path
    - **Using persistent volume for logs**: you have all the logs in the persistent volume (which is usually nfs or efs)
    - **Not using anything for logs**: you will lose logs after job execution. [No Persistence Docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/manage-logs.html#no-persistence)
  - Using CeleryExecutor: [Celery Worker Log Persistence](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/manage-logs.html#celery-worker-log-persistence)
- If it is a local deployment, you can find the logs at the AIRFLOW_HOME path